# What does this part mean: " ........ for as long as there's been into continental air travel."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC. [British Airways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTaPtkTwniU&list=PL72jhKwankOjAGP4aeT5_XNp-l_Mc5kwF&index=2) (see: 25:40-25:47)

*Hong Kong is the airline's foothold in China. It's part of the colonial furniture a legacy of empire. It's been flying here **for as long as there's been into continental air travel.***

I did not understand the last sentence, particularly because of the part in bold. **"....for as long as there has been into ..."** does not seem to make any sense to me. So, I want to ask what does the part **"there has been into"** mean?

Comment: It's just a poor auto-subtitle. Inter-continental, not into continental.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a bad subtitle track [an eggcorn].

Comment: Auto generated subtitles on youtube are often inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mishearing it. He's actually saying:

> for as long as there's been **intercontinental** air travel.

Being British, the narrator has a non-rhotic accent, and thus doesn't pronounce the "r" there.

Comment: Actually, it's not just a mishearing. The youtube auto-generated subtitles are wrong, which has likely confused the OP.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I think many learners assume that (e.g.) YouTube subtitles are exact transcripts of what is being said.

Comment: @BillyKerr It could also be someone learning English in the US. It does sound like how I would pronounce "into continental."

Comment: @alphabet -Note also that not all Brits have non-rhotic accents.  There are several rhotic accent areas in the UK: Scotland, Northern Ireland, and the West Country (south west England).

Comment: @alphabet - note also that not all Americans have rhotic accents, notably in the New England, New York, 'Tidewater', 'Low Country', and southern Lousiana areas.